Can't change Time (from seconds to thousandths of a second)
Need to speed the transition of images, but can't change the seconds.
<item name="time" type="number" description="Switching interval" default="1" />

<Var expression="#time*0.001" threshold="$time">
    <Trigger>
        <VariableCommand name="newId" expression="int(#curId+1)%max(min($size,22),1)" persist="true" />
        <AnimationCommand target="ani" command="play" />
    </Trigger>
</Var>
<Var name="ani">
    <VariableAnimation loop="false" initPause="true">
        <AniFrame value="0" time="0" />
        <AniFrame value="1" time="800" />
        <Triggers>
            <Trigger action="end" condition="#ani==1">
                <VariableCommand name="curId" expression="#newId" persist="true" />
            </Trigger>
        </Triggers>
    </VariableAnimation>
</Var>`

I've try to change
expression="#time*0.001" threshold="$time"
to
expression="#time*0.0001" threshold="$time"
but doesn't affect the speed of transition.

For others that may be useful, I resolved the issue:
<Var expression="#time*0.01" threshold="$time">
    <Trigger>
        <VariableCommand name="newId" expression="int(#curId+1)%max(min($size,26),1)" persist="true" />
        <AnimationCommand target="ani" command="play" />
    </Trigger>
</Var>
<Var name="ani">
    <VariableAnimation initPause="true" loop="false">
            <AniFrame value="0" time="0" easeType="BackEaseIn"/>
            <AniFrame value="10" time="80"/>
        <Triggers>
            <Trigger action="end" condition="#ani==10">
                <VariableCommand name="curId" expression="#newId" persist="true" />
            </Trigger>
        </Triggers>
    </VariableAnimation>

